# SWF FancyBox - Closing Doesn't Shutdown FancyBox

Tags: fancybox, flash, refresh

I attempted these answers but to no avail...

[Fancy Box - how to refresh parent page when close iframe popup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269899/fancy-box-how-to-refresh-parent-page-when-close-iframe-popup)

I have a simple fancybox implementation on a set of SWF files:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".demo-videos").fancybox({
        maxWidth        : 600,
        maxHeight       : 450,
        openEffect      : 'fade',
        closeEffect     : 'fade',
        openSpeed       : 500,
        closeSpeed      : 500,
        allowfullscreen : 'true'
    });
});
```

The problem is when I close the fancybox window, the page remains dimmed and the only way to get the original parent back is to refresh.  Even clicking outside the fancybox, while it removes the dimmed background, does not return page to original state.  Scroll bar on right side, for example, is missing and page is truncated.

I have fancybox implemented elsewhere but this is the first time I've done so with an SWF source file.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any demo? I suspect you are using old jQuery version.

Comment: You're right - I was unintentionally using 1.6.3.  Upgraded and fancybox closes...  Thanks a bunch.  If you write up an answer, I will accept it.  Otherwise, I will try to close or delete this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded my version of Fancybox and jQuery and all is well.  Thanks Janis!  +1