# show iframe in popup DIV without refresh parent window

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have site where in one window can klick in many anchors, always when user click on anchor  = show div with Iframe and show data (palyer - golf csore card), but the parent window was refresh, then when user open 4-5 (score card) and close is history lenght long, because everytime was parent windows refresh, and it's not so good, I wanna click - read data in iframe then clocse div and when click on BACK BUTTON go on previous page

please help

JavaScript:

```
function fullWindowPopUp(AX, cis_turnaj, os_cis,pocet_kol, priezvisko, meno) {
    var Nheight = screen.height;;
    var Nwidth = screen.width;
    var NovaSirka = (Nwidth/2)-400;
    var NovaVyska = 155;

    if(pocet_kol=="" || pocet_kol==0) {
        document.getElementById("frameKarta").src='components/com_pgs/scorekarta.php?cis_turnaj='+cis_turnaj+'&os_cis='+os_cis+'&neex=1&priezvisko='+priezvisko+'&meno='+meno+' ';
    } else {
        document.getElementById("frameKarta").src='components/com_pgs/scorekarta.php?cis_turnaj='+cis_turnaj+'&os_cis='+os_cis+'&priezvisko='+priezvisko+'&meno='+meno+' ';
    }
    var divShow = document.getElementById(AX).style.display="block";
        document.getElementById(AX).style.width=Nwidth+"px";
        document.getElementById(AX).style.height=Nheight+"px";
        document.getElementById("scorePopUp").style.left=NovaSirka+'px';
        document.getElementById("scorePopUp").style.top=NovaVyska+'px';
        if(pocet_kol==1) { document.getElementById("frameKarta").style.height="298px"; }
        if(pocet_kol==2) {document.getElementById("frameKarta").style.height="357px"; }
        if(pocet_kol==3) { document.getElementById("frameKarta").style.height="417px"; }
        if(pocet_kol=="" || pocet_kol==0) { document.getElementById("frameKarta").style.height="295px"; }


    }

    function fullWindowPopUpClose (AX) {
        divShow = document.getElementById(AX).style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("frameKarta").src='components/com_pgs/blank.php';}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="dipoupscore" onclick="fullWindowPopUpClose('dipoupscore');"   style="display:none;margin:0px auto !important;text-align:center !important;top:0px; left:0px; position:fixed; background:url(templates/pgs_order/images/pozadie.png);z-index:9999;">
<div id="scorePopUp" style="text-align:center;position:relative;overflow:hidden;text-align:center;width:800px;padding:0px;border:7px #DBDBDB solid;border-radius:6px;">

    <iframe id="frameKarta" src="components/com_pgs/blank.php" style="border:none; ovreflow:hidden;width:100%; ">

    </iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269899/fancy-box-how-to-refresh-parent-page-when-close-iframe-popup

Comment: thnx ! but the link does not solve my problem ;-)